# How to handle unmapped requests in Spring MVC 3

Tags: spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I wanted to map all the unmapped requests to a 404 error page using spring mvc 3 and I configure the following in web.xml and controller for it:

**web.xml**

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error404</location>
</error-page>
```

**Request handler in controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/error404")
public String get404() {
    return "error-404.html";
}
```

Assuming I am running at domain **mydomain**, it works alright if I don't have a `/` in the unmapped request (e.g. `http://mydomain/abc`) but otherwise I still get the page `error-404.html` but I lose all the styling of the page.

So `http://mydomain/abc` works alright but `http://mydomain/abc/z` doesn't.

Could someone help me with it?

Thanks.

Comment: I solved it by redirecting the request to another request handler. Doing the following solved the problem:  `@RequestMapping(value="/error404")
 public String get404() {
  return "redirect:/err404";
 }`
 
 `@RequestMapping(value="/err404")
 public String pageNotFound() {
  return "error-404.html";
 }`. Thanks.

Comment: this is a horrible solution. You don't need a redirect to do this. Furthermore, a 404 error page should come with a 404 HTTP error status code, and you lose it by doing what you did. You probably use relative paths instead of absolute paths to your images and CSS files in your HTML page. Show us the code of this page.

Comment: @JBNizet: You're absolutely right. The page actually has url paths for all the links to css files and sources to images all relative. Reason why I had to redirect was even the links are relative on the page. Could you suggest any better approach to handle this problem? Do you still want me to post the code here?

Answer (score 2):

you can use ${pageContext.request.contextPath} in your page for all urls including anchor tag links..
like:

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/style/front.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```